# jupyter notebook - check if magic is available

Tags: python, jupyter

I am trying to call a python command from within javascript using the ipykernel.comm. The problem is that I want to use the same code regardless if I run python3 kernel or pyspark3 kernel. For the latter I need to run code with **%%local** cell magic, which does not work for the pure python 3 kernel.

How do I programmatically check if a given (frontend) magic is available?

I tried looking into `get_ipython().magics_manager.registry` but I feel that is not the way. I tried to look on the frontend (javascript) side but I also could not find it.

I thought maybe the source for sparkmagic will help me, but no luck. I do not know how to access `IPython.CodeCell.config_defaults`

sparkmagic's [kernel.js](https://github.com/jupyter-incubator/sparkmagic/blob/959c4be13a00f5f0aff155660c592411291d0546/sparkmagic/sparkmagic/kernels/sparkkernel/kernel.js)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the available magics via:

```
from IPython import get_ipython

line_magics = list(get_ipython().magics_manager.magics.get('line'))
cell_magics = list(get_ipython().magics_manager.magics.get('cell'))
```

Answer (score 3):

Instead of checking if the command is available you just use it and catch the exception if it is not supported.

Example:

```
from IPython.core.error import UsageError
try:
    %%local
except UsageError:
    print("Magic %%local not support in this kernel")
```

Comment: Unfortunately when I run it in PySpark3 kernel it gives invalid syntax error although the `%%local` is available.

Comment: Apparently PySpark syntax only accepts magic commands at the beginning of the line. In this case it seems to fail because of the indentation. This makes it a little harder to solve...